# How does one create a custom package feed in OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt

I have a number of custom packages that I'm building under OpenWRT that I'd like to add to a custom feed so I can have IoT devices pull updates for these custom packages.

I've looked through all of the OpenWRT docs and done several google searches without finding any details. Where can I find documentation, a tutorial, or an example of creating the files required for a custom feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [OpenWRT official doc](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/feeds):

### Router configuration

Configure the OpenWRT router to know about the new custom feed location; In `/etc/opkg.conf` add something like this

```
# customfeeds
src/gz custompackages http://s3.amazonaws.com/mycustompackages-orwhatever
```

You will also need to accept your custom signing key assuming you do package signing.

```
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/mycustompackages/public.key
opkg-key add public.key
```

### Server files needed

Now you need to setup the HTTP server, I've successfully an S3 bucket for a while.

- `Packages.gz` - compressed version of Package
- `Packages` - uncompressed version of Packages
- `Packages.sig` -
- `custom_public.key` -
- `yourpackage.ipk` - the actual ipk package file to be installed

### How to create the files

- You can create the ipk file using `ipkg-build`; I've used [this version](https://github.com/lede-project/source/blob/master/scripts/ipkg-build)
- You can create the `Packages` index file using `ipkg-make-index.sh` script. (I've used [this one](https://github.com/lede-project/source/blob/master/scripts/ipkg-make-index.sh))
- Get `Packages.gz` by gzipping the `Packages` file
- Use [usign](https://git.openwrt.org/project/usign.git) to create the Private/Public keys for Package signing
- Also use usign to create the `Packages.sig` file

### Sample script

This sample assumes your private key is `private.key`

```
ipkg-build mypackage .
mv mypackage.ipk packages/
cd packages
../ipkg-make-index.sh . > Packages
usign -S -m Packages -s ../keys/private.key -x Packages.sig
gzip -fk Packages
```

Comment: Hi @preezzzy. How are you building usign for local use? Manually? I would have imagined there was a way to build from the OpenWRT package.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - Yes I am building usign manually on my development machine. (Ubuntu)

Comment: Hi @preezzzy. I'm still working to automate this, sorry for my slow responses. Is there any reason to be able to preserve old versions of packages? It seems like this is unnecessary, the packages directory could be rebuilt with the latest versions, the only downside is that clients could only upgrade, not downgrade. Thoughts?